# Issuing Passport : Inconsistency in Date of Birth in all documents other than birth certificate

Tags: passports, legal, india, paperwork

I want to apply for the passport but the DOB in my birth certificate (after 1989) is different from my rest of the documents.I mean ALL the documents.

What should I do? And my birth Certificate (from a certified authority) does not have my name but only my fathers and mothers first name and rest of the details.

What best can be done in this case ? Creating an affidavit will do the trick ? Please guide me the possible ways.

Comment: having no name in birth certificate is not an issue at all, is there a real valid reason to have different date of births and are they off by one or two days or by months?

Comment: @skv differ exactly by one year . It was since childhood . so.. what can i possibly do now?

Comment: Is it me or is there no travelling intent behind this question? I think what you need is legal advice, and we can't provide that on TSE.

Comment: @JoErNanO I did think of that angle, but since it is a travel document thought of answering.. yeah more of a legal question to me... but the only travel intent comes in my answer regarding purpose of travel and ECR and things like that

Answer (score 2):

I think if you can just skip the ECR check category then your required documents become just (as per http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/docAdvisor/attachmentAdvFresh)

1. Proof of present address (utility bill etc)
2. Birth Certificate

If you go through this route and if you want to be in NON ECR category then you get into Matric Certificate as a requirement which may become an issue for you.  I am not sure if having that ECR stamp is a big problem, if it is then you need to go through a long route.  If you are planning to go outside India immediately and want NON ECR status for some reason then its an issue.

https://www.kaanoon.com/16777/dob-change-in-matric-certificate has some guidance on this

Comment: Thank you for the answer . Can I go for the short-cut and make a new DOB certificate ? You know what I mean

Comment: Thats not very easy these days I did try, but if you can then yes

Comment: And what about affidavit ? won't help?

Comment: affidavit for what... change of date of birth, I am not sure if it is an accepted procedure at all, only replacement certificates work in most cases I know of